# How to split an expression or comma separated string to column names in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone please help me to split the following string

```
'Column1, To_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), Column3'
```

into

**COLUMN_LIST**

```
Column1     
To_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  
Column3
```

in oracle

Comment: you'd better sharing sample data and expected output explicitly with us.

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this -- PL/SQL and `execute immediate`.

Comment: To find how to split strings in Oracle on this website, Google for the following phrase (including the site: portion): **Split string into rows site:stackoverflow.com** You will find many (MANY!) results; this is one of the most common questions asked here. Obviously many people aren't used to do some research on their own before asking a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I don't see it. What is dynamic in this OP's request? I see a simple tokenization of an input string - he/she is not asking to create new **columns** based on actual text in the input string, only new rows.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I'm pretty sure the OP wants the *results* of those expressions, not just to split the string.

Comment: @mathguy - I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you proposed. The comma in the `To_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` token means a simple "split on comma" solution won't produce the result the OP wants.

Comment: @Tapas - does your input really look exactly as you posted? Because the comma in the middle of `To_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` is going to make any solution extremely complicated. Normally a CSV file (e.g. exported from Excel") would have wrapped the tokens (cells) in field delimiters e.g. `'Column1, "To_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')", Column3` precisely to prevent commas in the data colliding with the separator.

Comment: @APC - good point, thank you for reopening the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRIM(regexp_substr(a.text, a.regExp, 1, level, null, 2)) names
FROM (SELECT 'Column1, to_date(Column2, ''DD/MM/YYYY''), Column3, TO_NUMBER(''123'', ''999''), Column4,Column5' text
           , '(^|,)(([^,]*\([^\(\)]*\))|[^\(\),]*)' regExp
        FROM dual) a
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(a.text, regExp, 1, level, null, 2) is not null
```

result is:
Column1
to_date(Column2, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
Column3
TO_NUMBER('123', '999')
Column4
Column5

I hope this is what you needed :)